# Mental institution

Tags: meaning

Is a mental institution a broad term that encompasses all of institutions like asylums, psychiatric hospitals etc. or can it be used as a standalone name for a place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase itself [has been growing less popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22mental%20institution%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20mental%20institution%20%22%3B%2Cc0), so it's hard for me to say what lingering applications it may have that differ from older, broader uses. I have only heard the term used to describe a residential treatment facility which focuses on mental health disorders, and (generally but not quite exclusively) acute episodes of mental health problems. In that mode it would fit for an asylum or psychiatric hospital, but not for, say, a day-treatment facility that focuses on eating disorders. It could also describe a particular, physical location with those properties ("that building is a mental institution.").

I personally would probably not use the phrase without a pretty compelling outside reason, as it has some less-than-great connotations (much like the word "asylum", which has itself fallen out of fashion in this usage). More popular, modern terms include *mental health [facility/hospital/clinic/etc.]* and, increasingly, *behavioral health [facility/hospital/clinic/etc.]*.